# Understanding Apple's documentation (same init 4 times)

Tags: swift

I really try to get into the custom reading Apple's official documentation. But to be honest: I got my problems getting the stuff.

[image: Multiple inits]

**What's here the difference between the four 'String init(describing: Subject)'?**

Source: [Apple documentation - String](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/#converting-other-types-to-strings)

Comment: Follow each overloads' documentation: they have different generic type parameter constraints.

Comment: When clicking the 4 identical looking overloads, the detail pages reveal different details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to protocol conformance and initialiser overloading.

`init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : TextOutputStreamable`

`init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : CustomStringConvertible`

`init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : CustomStringConvertible, Subject : TextOutputStreamable`

`init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject)`

Clicking through to the definition of the initialiser gives the following information explaining what each does.

> Use this initializer to convert an instance of any type to its
> preferred representation as a String instance. The initializer creates
> the string representation of instance in one of the following ways,
> depending on its protocol conformance:
>
> If instance conforms to the TextOutputStreamable protocol, the result
> is obtained by calling instance.write(to: s) on an empty string s.
>
> If instance conforms to the CustomStringConvertible protocol, the
> result is instance.description.
>
> If instance conforms to the CustomDebugStringConvertible protocol, the
> result is instance.debugDescription.
>
> An unspecified result is supplied automatically by the Swift standard
> library.
>
> For example, this custom Point struct uses the default representation
> supplied by the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

The detail page talks about the differences.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(describing:)-67ncf

> The initializer creates the string representation of instance in one of the following ways, depending on its protocol conformance:

> If instance conforms to the TextOutputStreamable protocol, the result is obtained by calling instance.write(to: s) on an empty string s.

> If instance conforms to the CustomStringConvertible protocol, the result is instance.description.

> If instance conforms to the CustomDebugStringConvertible protocol, the result is instance.debugDescription.

> An unspecified result is supplied automatically by the Swift standard library.

If you type

```
String(describing
```

In Xcode and "Jump to Definition" you will see how they are defined

```
public init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject)

@inlinable public init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : CustomStringConvertible

@inlinable public init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : TextOutputStreamable

@inlinable public init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : CustomStringConvertible, Subject : TextOutputStreamable
```

The part after the `where` is what matches the descriptions from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Despite sharing the same name, each of those overloads has different [constraints on their generic and associated types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics/#Associated-Types-with-a-Generic-Where-Clause), but that summary section on Apple's documentation page doesn't display those constraints, hence the visual ambiguity.

But if you follow each link to their own page, you'll see how the constraints are different:

- [First](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(describing:)-588wb). `init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : TextOutputStreamable`
- [Second](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(describing:)-hsqw). `init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : CustomStringConvertible`
- [Third](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(describing:)-6ttci). `init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject) where Subject : CustomStringConvertible, Subject : TextOutputStreamable`
- [Forth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(describing:)-67ncf). `init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject)`
- [Fifth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(reflecting:)). `init<Subject>(reflecting subject: Subject)`